# undefined symbols:___ isplatformversionatleast

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode10.3

I have used pod "SinchRTC" and I am able to build and run the project in debug mode. But now when I am achieving the project, I am getting the error :--[image]

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"___isPlatformVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
  -[RTCMTLRenderer setupTexturesForFrame:] in Sinch(libSinch-dist.a-arm64-master.o)
  -[RTCMTLVideoView frameRotation] in Sinch(libSinch-dist.a-arm64-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is this a framework issue because I am not getting any solutions?

I want to upload this build. Can you please provide me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Xcode you are using to achieving?

Comment: I am using Xcode 10.3

Comment: Check once the below answer.

Comment: Check it with Xcode 11 beta or later version.

Comment: Because isPlatformVersionAtLeast are in iOS SDK 13

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you have arm64 architecture turned on in your project's build settings. Also, if you are trying to use the same binary for both iPhone 5 and 6 (and others), make sure that and that 'Build for Active Architecture Only' is turned off.

**Or**

*Try this*

isPlatformVersionAtLeast are in iOS SDK 13, so would require Xcode 11 beta. I think you are getting the error because you are using an earlier Xcode version Xcode 10.3 .